# Repeatable random data generation in Swift 4

Tags: swift, random, generator

I'm writing tests in Swift 4.  I want to generate thousands of rows of test input data.  I want the test input data to be random.

But I want my tests to be repeatable: the same data needs to be generated for each run of all tests.

How is this achieved in Swift?  In Java I've always relied on the Apache commons [RandomDataGenerator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html).  I've explored `arc4random` and `drand48`, but these don't seem to provide the repeatability I require.

Comment: I don't understand how "drand48 [doesn't] provide the repeatability". It does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Swift has no native random number generation capabilities. You can call C library functions from Swift, though. Any page on C random number library functions will describe them to you.

For example, you could just seed `srand48` with the same constant every time and call `drand48` to get your numbers.

```
(1...3).forEach {_ in
    srand48(100)
    (1...3).forEach {_ in print(drand48())}
}
/*
 // spot the repetition:
 0.25105890266514
 0.208948404851498
 0.940927909958315
 0.25105890266514
 0.208948404851498
 0.940927909958315
 0.25105890266514
 0.208948404851498
 0.940927909958315
*/
```

Some other C library functions are unavailable from Swift so you'd have to write that part of the code in C. No big deal.